# NET Framework Examples - not fully working examples?

Tags: .net, c++-cli

I tried to execute the following [example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.diagnostics.process(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
#using <System.dll>

using namespace System;
using namespace System::Diagnostics;
using namespace System::ComponentModel;

// Opens the Internet Explorer application.
void OpenApplication(String^ myFavoritesPath)
{
    // Start Internet Explorer. Defaults to the home page.
    Process::Start("IExplore.exe");

    // Display the contents of the favorites folder in the browser.
    Process::Start(myFavoritesPath);
}

// Opens urls and .html documents using Internet Explorer.
void OpenWithArguments()
{
    // url's are not considered documents. They can only be opened
    // by passing them as arguments.
    Process::Start("IExplore.exe", "www.northwindtraders.com");

    // Start a Web page using a browser associated with .html and .asp files.
    Process::Start("IExplore.exe", "C:\\myPath\\myFile.htm");
    Process::Start("IExplore.exe", "C:\\myPath\\myFile.asp");
}

// Uses the ProcessStartInfo class to start new processes,
// both in a minimized mode.
void OpenWithStartInfo()
{
    ProcessStartInfo^ startInfo = gcnew ProcessStartInfo("IExplore.exe");
    startInfo->WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle::Minimized;
    Process::Start(startInfo);
    startInfo->Arguments = "www.northwindtraders.com";
    Process::Start(startInfo);
}

int main()
{
    // Get the path that stores favorite links.
    String^ myFavoritesPath = Environment::GetFolderPath(Environment::SpecialFolder::Favorites);
    OpenApplication(myFavoritesPath);
    OpenWithArguments();
    OpenWithStartInfo();
}
```

But I get alot of errors:

```
    21  IntelliSense: Zu viele Argumente im Funktionsaufruf.    c:\users\edd\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\system\system\main.cpp   44  21  System
    2   IntelliSense: PCH-Warnung: Es wurde keine geeignete Stelle für das Header-Ende gefunden. Es wurde keine Intellisense-PCH-Datei generiert.   c:\users\edd\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\system\system\main.cpp   3   1   System
    14  IntelliSense: Es wurde ein ";" erwartet.    c:\users\edd\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\system\system\main.cpp   33  41  System
    5   IntelliSense: Ein Name gefolgt von "::" muss ein Klassen- oder Namespacename sein.  c:\users\edd\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\system\system\main.cpp   4   17  System
    6   IntelliSense: Ein Name gefolgt von "::" muss ein Klassen- oder Namespacename sein.  c:\users\edd\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\system\system\main.cpp   5   17  System
    7   IntelliSense: Ein Name gefolgt von "::" muss ein Klassen- oder Namespacename sein.  c:\users\edd\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\system\system\main.cpp   13  5   System
    8   IntelliSense: Ein Name gefolgt von "::" muss ein Klassen- oder Namespacename sein.  c:\users\edd\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\system\system\main.cpp   22  5   System
    9   IntelliSense: Ein Name gefolgt von "::" muss ein Klassen- oder Namespacename sein.  c:\users\edd\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\system\system\main.cpp   25  5   System
    10  IntelliSense: Ein Name gefolgt von "::" muss ein Klassen- oder Namespacename sein.  c:\users\edd\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\system\system\main.cpp   26  5   System
    15  IntelliSense: Ein Name gefolgt von "::" muss ein Klassen- oder Namespacename sein.  c:\users\edd\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\system\system\main.cpp   34  30  System
    16  IntelliSense: Ein Name gefolgt von "::" muss ein Klassen- oder Namespacename sein.  c:\users\edd\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\system\system\main.cpp   35  5   System
    17  IntelliSense: Ein Name gefolgt von "::" muss ein Klassen- oder Namespacename sein.  c:\users\edd\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\system\system\main.cpp   37  5   System
    19  IntelliSense: Ein Name gefolgt von "::" muss ein Klassen- oder Namespacename sein.  c:\users\edd\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\system\system\main.cpp   43  30  System
    20  IntelliSense: Ein Name gefolgt von "::" muss ein Klassen- oder Namespacename sein.  c:\users\edd\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\system\system\main.cpp   43  57  System
    4   IntelliSense: Der Name muss ein Namespacename sein. c:\users\edd\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\system\system\main.cpp   3   17  System
    18  IntelliSense: Der Bezeichner ""string"" ist nicht definiert.    c:\users\edd\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\system\system\main.cpp   43  5   System
    12  IntelliSense: Der Bezeichner ""startInfo"" ist nicht definiert. c:\users\edd\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\system\system\main.cpp   33  23  System
    11  IntelliSense: Der Bezeichner ""ProcessStartInfo"" ist nicht definiert.  c:\users\edd\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\system\system\main.cpp   33  5   System
    13  IntelliSense: Der Bezeichner ""gcnew"" ist nicht definiert. c:\users\edd\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\system\system\main.cpp   33  35  System
    3   IntelliSense: ""#using"" erfordert, dass C++/CLI aktiviert ist. c:\users\edd\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\system\system\main.cpp   1   20  System
Fehler  1   error C1190: Für verwalteten Zielcode ist eine /clr-Option erforderlich.    c:\users\edd\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\system\system\main.cpp   1   1   System
```

Unfortunately the errors are in german.

Is my assumption correct that the examples are only pseudo code for demonstration and are no fully working examples, or is it my mistake?

I know I have to enter my own paths and stuff.

Answer (score 1):

> Der Bezeichner "gcnew" ist nicht definiert

Google Translate says that translates to `The identifier "gcnew" is not defined`.

I'm guessing that you didn't create a C++/CLI project. Perhaps a plain C++ project, or a C++/CX project.

On my system, the C++/CLI projects are listed in Visual Studio 2010's New Project window under `Other Languages`, `Visual C++`, `CLR`. You probably want `CLR Console Application`.

Comment: Yes I choosed "Win32 - Consoleapplication". The project types you mentioned are not listed in visual studio 2010. At least I could not find them yet.

Comment: wow... now I have the known infinite project create loop bug and cant create another project... omg